# VBA: How to Reference Large Unicode Characters like Paperclip?

Tags: vba, unicode

I know that similar question has been asked many times before but all I found was about characters up to 2-byte long. I need:

```
MyString = ""
```

The PAPERCLIP is (U+1F4CE) (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4ce/index.htm) and the

```
ChrW(128206) 'throws an error
```

HOW to reference the unicode chars longer than 2 bytes?

Comment: Talking of Paperclip - I can use it as a caption of the Command Button, Text Label, Text Box... I can NOT use it for MsgBox - it displays "??" (I'm using MS Access 2010)

Comment: Hmm, odd, I guess it uses MesssageBoxA() to display the string instead of the Unicode version, MessageBoxW().  Accidents certainly *can* happen, you're battling 25 years of appcompat :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job that your text editor *ought* to take care of.  My memory of the VBA editor is hazy, I don't recollect any way to force the text encoding of the source code file and trying it quickly with the VBA editor in Excel 2013 looks very unpromising.  It turns the utf-16 surrogate pair into two question marks.

Switching to another editor could work, Notepad works fine with the Encoding setting in the Save As dialog forced to "Unicode" for example.  But that is hardship, with high odds that the string gets mangled again when you continue editing with the VBA editor.  The workaround is to specify the surrogate pair explicitly.  Try:

```
 MyString = ChrW(&HD83D) & ChrW(&HDCCE)
```

Google "utf16 surrogate pair calculator" if you need to do this more than once.

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't trying to type special characters directly into the editor anyway as I found it unreliable (sometimes it gets corrupted with new version, different editor, etc.) It was just a quick way to explain what I want to do.